# Error: has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++

I am having the problem: has initializer but incomplete type while using struct:

in a hpp file:

```
class A
{
private:
   struct videoDT;
};
```

in a cpp file:

```
struct A::videoDT
{
  videoDT(int b) : a(b){}

  int a;
};

void test()
{
   struct videoDT test(1);
}
```

Then I have the problem:

Error: has initializer but incomplete type

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should't it be 'struct A::videoDT test(1);'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `test()` doesn't have access to `A`'s private types.

This compiles for me:

```
class A
{
private:
    friend void test();
    struct videoDT;
};

struct A::videoDT
{
    videoDT(int b) : a(b){}

    int a;
};

void test()
{
    A::videoDT test(1);
}
```

Comment: @Joesy: I first misread the question. See the revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your `test` function you declare a local type `struct videoDT`, but never define it. Not surpisingly, the compiler complains about an object of incomplete type being initialized. End of story.

How did you expect it to work? If you wanted your declaration to use `A::videoDT` type, then you should have used the qualified name for the type - `A::videoDT` - since that's what that type is called. However, the code will not compile anyway, since `A::videoDT` is private in `A` and `test` has no access to it.

In other words, it is hard to figure out what you were trying to do. Provide some explanations or code that make more sense.

Comment: I really doubt that `struct videoDT test(1);` could be parsed as a type declaration.

Comment: @sbi: In situations when name lookup does not find a previous declaration for the `struct` type, I believe, it is is interpreted as a declaration of a new type - a local one. No?

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler processes the .hpp file, it needs to infer the memory footprint and layout of class A. For this reason, it needs to know the memory layout of struct videoDT.

The error is the compiler complaining that it doesn't know what `struct videoDT` is, since you define it in the .cpp file.

To solve the error, you need to define the `struct` in a .hpp file that gets included before your original .hpp. Alternatively, you can use the pimpl idiom and change `class A` to:

```
class A
{
private:
    struct videoDT* pVideoDT;
}
```

If you do this, then you no longer need to define the struct in a header file just to compile class A. However, the pimpl idiom is an advanced technique and I suggest reading up on it before deciding to use it.