# variable "ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, unsigned int> AcsHcs::Cache::cnt" has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: api, ace

I am porting my windows code to linux.
 when i am using ACE_Atomic_Op api, compiler is throwing some error as shown below

```
variable "ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, unsigned int> AcsHcs::Cache::cnt" 
has initializer but incomplete type"
```

my code is as follows:

in Cache.h file i have

```
static ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, unsigned int> cnt;
```

and in cache.cpp i am declaring cnt as

```
ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, unsigned int> Cache::cnt = 0;
```

this works fine in windows, but it is throwing error in linux

can anyone tell me whats the problem is?

thanks in advance

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287428/error-has-initializer-but-incomplete-type

Comment: Do you have included ace/Atomic_Op.h?

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking an include, please add `ace/Atomic_Op.h` to your source file. Because of platform differences it sometimes happens that on a platform your get an include for free, when porting to another platform you have to add an explicit include.